# xdebug, Netbeans, and MAMP - waiting for connection (forever)

Tags: netbeans, xdebug, mamp

So here's my setup in a nutshell: MAMP, project is in Codeigniter framework, just set up xdebug and Netbeans.  I also have the xdebug helper extension for Chrome.

The problem is that when I try to run debug in Netbeans, "Waiting for connection (netbeans-xdebug)" appears and never goes away. I'm unable to perform any debug actions.

xdebug appears to have installed correctly, as it appears in phpinfo and the settings appear correct - except for one thing that strikes me as strange. The master value of the idekey is what it should be (netbeans-xdebug) but the local value is different (it's actually the username of my system account). Does this local value matter and how would I go about changing it?

Also, following advice for using the xdebug helper extension, I selected "do not open web browser" in the project properties advanced options. There's a little alert on that "advanced web configuration" dialog saying "project mapping might be needed" but as of now nothing is filled out there. Also on that dialog, debugger proxy host is blank with port 9001, not sure if that's at all relevant.

The relevant section of my php.ini is as follows:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.default_enable=1
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```

The xdebug.so file I'm using is copied and pasted from the latest komodo download.

Many, many thanks in advance for any help - this is a very frustrating one!

Answer (score 1):

Dude, i'm using netbeans+wamp+vista+chrome+drupal and i've had a strange behavior. The first time i run netbeans to debug i can't have any breakpoints. Pay attention to uncheck the option "stop in the first line". So, i put some breakpoints and i was able to start debugging. It is strange but i'm only able to debug from the second time!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the `xdebug.remote_autostart=1` line in php.ini, and I don't have the 'do not open web browser' option enabled. It went wrong when I tried to do it your way.

When I use xdebug, I press the debug button in Netbeans and it redirects me to the browser with a cookie appended to the url (from the project's run configuration) like this:

```
http://yoururl.org/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
```

I'd try getting it to work like that first, then worry about the more advanced option of having it always on.